# Null space squared Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

I have a matrix $G$ that is a row-normalized adjacency matrix of a connected graph. This means that all entries are $\geq 0$ and every row sums to one. The diagonal only contains zeros.

From the Perron-Frobenius theorem, I know that $G$ has a unique (largest) eigenvalue 1 (the eigenvector is the vector of ones). Therefore, I know that the Laplacian matrix $(I-G)$ has a unique eigenvalue 0 (the eigenvector is again the vector of ones), so the null space of $(I-G)$ is of dimension 1 and is proportional to this vector of ones.

Now my question is how to prove that the null space of $(I-G)^2$ is also of dimension 1 (and not of 2). Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: If this is an undirected graph, then $(I - G)$ is symmetric. In general: for a matrix $A$, $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same nullspace. Applying this with $A = I-G$ gives you the result you're after

Comment: If this is a directed graph: the Perron-Frobenius theorem also tells you that $1$ will be a *simple* eigenvalue of $G$, which is to say that the algebraic multiplicity will be $1$. It follows that $(I - G)$ and $(I - G)^2$ have the same null space dimension.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, thank you for your answer. How do you conclude that $(I-G)$ and $(I-G)^2$ have the same null space dimension from the algebraic multiplicity of 1? This is exactly the result I am after.

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is the maximum dimension of the null space of $(I - G)^k$ for all integers $k \geq 0$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, thank you again for your answer. However, my question is why this is the case, as it is not obvious to me. Could you provide me with a reference or point me into the right direction? I am trying to understand why algebraic multiplicity of 1 implies the stated.

Comment: Well ultimately that depends on your definition of algebraic multiplicity. If you want a reference, I know that "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler addresses this directly, and most introductory linear algebra texts should say something about this as well. If you are familiar with Jordan canonical form, there is a quick explanation to be made in those terms